# Using ZXing in a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, barcode, zxing, barcode-scanner

I have searched all over the place and I can't find a working solution on how to implement ZXing in a Fragment. Multiple sources have told me that this is right, but onActivityResult never gets called.

The button click triggers the scanner to open

```
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_barcode,container,false);
    final Button openBC = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btnOpen);
    openBC.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            //This opens up the Barcode Scanner
            IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(getActivity());
            integrator.setDesiredBarcodeFormats(IntentIntegrator.ALL_CODE_TYPES);
            integrator.setPrompt("Scan A barcode or QR Code");
            integrator.setCameraId(0);
            integrator.setBeepEnabled(false);
            integrator.setBarcodeImageEnabled(false);
            integrator.initiateScan();
        }
    });


    return view;
}
```

This is where the result of the scan should be processed, but it never gets here

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(result != null) {
        if(result.getContents() == null) {
            Log.d("MainActivity", "Cancelled scan");
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "canceled",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Log.d("MainActivity", "Scanned");
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Scanned: " + result.getContents(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }else {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try passing the Fragment to the IntentIntegrator constructor. Also where are you overriding the onActivityResult? In the Fragment or the Activity?

Comment: The `onActivityResult` method of the activity which contains your fragment will be called.

Comment: @jgriffin Yes I do override the onActivityResult, and I have tried passing the fragment in.

Answer (score 2):

This happen because you override onActivityResult from Fragment but initialize intentIntegrator `IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(getActivity());` with activity.

You are two options:
1) Override `onActivityResult` inside Activity
2) Change initialization passing fragment inside activity instance.

This should be help you:

Assuming that fragment is called MyFragment:

```
IntentIntegrator.forFragment(MyFragment.this).initiateScan();
```

[ZXing Minimal](https://github.com/andreipro/zxing-android-minimal)

Comment: It tells me:   forFragment (android.app.Fragment) in IntentIntegrator cannot be applied to (anonymous android.view.View.OnClickListener)

Comment: this becaus you using "this" inside onclicklistener you passing interface instead of fragment instance. Use "NameOfYourFragment".this

Comment: It still gives me this. 
forFragment
(android.app.Fragment)
in IntentIntegrator cannot be applied
to
(com.example.d_jackson.pro2.Barcode)

Comment: Do I need to import/add dependency anything different to use the forFragment?

Comment: if you don't use ZXing Minimal , yes. See link inside my answer. There you find the tutorial @DanJackson

Answer (score 2):

If the fragment is imported from 
import `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` then you should use `IntentIntegrator.forSupportFragment(this).initiateScan();`

If the framgment is imported from 
import `android.app.Fragment` then `IntentIntegrator.forFragment(MyFragment.this).initiateScan();` can be used..

Comment: I have used `android.app.Fragment` but I am getting  `error: cannot find symbol
            IntentIntegrator.forFragment(this).initiateScan();`

Answer (score 0):

My solution for this problem is this:

```
 IntentIntegrator  i =IntentIntegrator.forSupportFragment(SlideshowFragment.this);
            i.setDesiredBarcodeFormats(IntentIntegrator.QR_CODE_TYPES);
            i.setPrompt("ESCANEAR CODIGO");
            i.setCameraId(0);
            i.setOrientationLocked(false);
            i.getMoreExtras();
            i.setBeepEnabled(true);
            i.setBarcodeImageEnabled(false);
            i.initiateScan();
```